# Moving inflated Layout/View to a new position in an animated way

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, layout-inflater

I'm inflating a layout to show it on the screen.
Now I want to move that layout partially off screen. I tried that using `.animate().translationX(-500)` on the inflated layout. It moved off screen exactly how I wanted it to look:

**Before:**

[image: before moving]

**After:**

[image: after moving]

But now I have the problem that the area which the layout originally occupied is not clickable (e.g. can't swipe between homescreens, only works outside the blue marked area).

[image: not clickable area]

How can I solve that, so blue area is clickable after moving, but the remaing area of the layout (red area) could still register clicks (e.g. if I wanted to move it back in with an onClickListener)?
I think I have to work with `updateViewLayout()` function of the `windowManager`, but I don't know what I should change regarding the parameters.

**Edit 1:**

Here is the code. The translation is triggered by the button:

**overlay.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d8ff0000"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="245dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum "
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="X"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginStart="27dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Service which inflates the layout:

**OverlayService.java**

```
public class FloatingMenu extends Service{

    private WindowManager wm;
    private LinearLayout ll;
    private boolean isPushedToSide = true;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        ll = new LinearLayout(this);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50, 255, 255, 255));
        ll.setLayoutParams(llParameters);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        parameters.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ll = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
        final Button b = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isPushedToSide) {
                    ll.animate().translationX(0);
                    isPushedToSide = false;
                }else {
                    ll.animate().translationX(-450);
                    isPushedToSide = true;
                }
            }
        });
        wm.addView(ll, parameters);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

While continuing my research I found out that `.animate().translationX()` only moves the position where the view is rendered and not the view itself. That also explains why after using `.animate().translationX()` the onclick event still gets triggered at the same position as before "moving" the layout.

Now I need to find a way to move the actual view to my desired position combining with an animation. Any ideas how to do that?

**Edit 3:**
I found a lot of posts with similar problems and if I'm right the solution to the problem is using `ObjectAnimator` instead of `.animate().translationX()`.
I tried replacing that part in my code, so that the `onClickListener` now looks like this:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (isPushedToSide) {
            //ll.animate().translationX(0);
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ll, "translationX", 0).setDuration(250).start();
            isPushedToSide = false;
        }else {
            //ll.animate().translationX(-450);
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ll, "translationX", -450).setDuration(250).start();
            isPushedToSide = true;
         }
    }
});
```

`ll` is the LinearLayout I have inflated, containing the `Lorem ipsum` text and `Button`.
Again the animation itself works fine, but behaves still the same way. I still need to click the original position of the button to fire the `onClickListener` and the blue area is still not clickable.

**Edit 4:**

Was trying out the suggestion to use`.invalidate()` to update the actual position. However it didn't work. I'm not sure if used it correct though.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (isPushedToSide) {
            //ll.animate().translationX(0);
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ll, "translationX", 0).setDuration(250).start();
            ll.invalidate();
            isPushedToSide = false;
        }else {
            //ll.animate().translationX(-450);
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ll, "translationX", -450).setDuration(250).start();
            ll.invalidate();
            isPushedToSide = true;
         }
    }
});
```

I also tried changing the x value of `LayoutParams` and calling `wm.updateViewLayou(ll, updatedParameters)`, which worked fine. When I moved the overlay 100px to the right, the area which triggers `onClickListener` also gets pushed 100px to the right. The problem is that I was only able to move the overlay within the boundaries of the actual screen and what I need is to move it off screen. Tied negative values, but that didn't work either.

What I essentially need is a drawer navigation but with a limited height (at least that's I think what I need). Gonna see if I can get something to work properly that way.

**Edit 5:**

Corrected my code so that `.inflate()` gets called when the animation has finished, but it still behaves the same way:

ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ll, "translationX", 0).setDuration(250);

```
anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        b.invalidate();
        text.invalidate();
        frame.invalidate();
        ll.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {}
});
anim.start();
```

I also recorded two .gifs showing the problem. I set the `gravity` to `CENTER` on the second one.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the creator of the guide I used for creating such `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` windows and he helped me out.

Here is the code:

```
public class Fw  extends Service {

    private WindowManager wm;
    private boolean isPushedToSide = true;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters;
    Button b;
    View inflating_layout;
    LayoutInflater li;
    ValueAnimator animator;

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflating_layout = li.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);

        b = (Button) inflating_layout.findViewById(R.id.button);

        parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        parameters.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;

        isPushedToSide = true;

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isPushedToSide) {

                    isPushedToSide = false;

                    animator  = ValueAnimator.ofInt(parameters.x, parameters.x-450);
                    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                            int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                            updateView(inflating_layout, val);

                        }
                    });
                    animator.setDuration(250);
                    animator.start();

                } else {

                    animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(parameters.x, parameters.x+450);
                    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                            int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                            updateView(inflating_layout, val);

                        }
                    });
                    animator.setDuration(250);
                    animator.start();


                    isPushedToSide = true;
                }
            }
        });
        wm.addView(inflating_layout, parameters);
    }

    public void updateView(View view, Integer x) {
        if (view != null) {
            if (x != null) parameters.x = x;
            wm.updateViewLayout(view, parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Now everything seems to work fine. Only the sliding animation is flickering a bit at the border of the screen. With a slower speed e.g. `.setDuration(2500)` that doesn't happen. I don't know if it's because of the emulator or another reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think easy way to solve that problem is animate changing property "width" instead translate your layout.

hope it helps

Comment: But wouldn't that method still show all the content of the layout, just squeezed together to fit the new width?

Comment: yes, it'll resize your layout, You need exectly hide part of your layout? Can you please show the snippet of your code? Animation part

Comment: Yes, if I would only change the width property it wouldn't look good when I add content later. I will add my code to the start post later.

Comment: You can try to call .invalidate() for all child views of your layout, after animatoin finished. I'm not sure, but guess, that will update actual position.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the start post.

Comment: think you need call invalidate() AFTER animation will finished. and you have to call it for each child view. Now it calls at the same time with animation starts.
Do you use option "Show layout boundaries" from developer options? It's very helpfull sometimes..

Comment: Updated my post once again. Thanks for the tip with the dev setting.

Comment: Wow, that's very strange behavior. Try setOnclickListener(null) for your button, when animation start, and set again, when animation will finished. Sure, that's not solution, but it may helps to localize problem

Comment: I just posted a solution. But thank you anyway for your help :)